# How can i fetch the following data?

Tags: android, json

I want to fetch the male object out of this code so that my output displays all the gender
having male in it.

```
  {
   "contacts": [
      {
            "id": "c200",
            "name": "Ravi Tamada",
            "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "c201",
            "name": "Johnny Depp",
            "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
            "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
           }
    },
```

This is the json code im trying to fetch

`if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

```
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);


                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                    if(TAG_GENDER == male ){


                    String name = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);


                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    contact.put(TAG_GENDER, name);

                    contactList.add(contact);
                }}  }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
         else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }`
```

Comment: where is your parsing code that you tried?

Comment: what is `if(TAG_GENDER == male ){`? what is `TAG_GENDER` and `male`?

Comment: private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

this is what i declared in the code:  
 private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
  private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
  private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";

Comment: @user3422497 what is `TAG_GENDER`?

Answer (score 0):

Here "{" show json object and "[" show json array so we will create json object and then jsonArray like that..

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JsonObjectKey);

            // if( jsonObj!=null)
            // {
            JSONArray list = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");// here your json array aname
            // if(list!=null)
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
//here you will fetch your all values that in your array..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am modifying your for loop..

```
          for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++)
           {
           JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            if((JSONObject)contacts.get(i)).get("gender").toString().equals("male") ){


            String name = (JSONObject)contacts.get(i)).get("name").toString();


            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

            contact.put(TAG_GENDER, name);

            contactList.add(contact);
        }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some correction you need to do.

1. declare your hash map outside the for loop
2. instead of using '==' in if loop use .equals